# Error 'zip END header not found' in intellij maven while updating from Java 8 to OpenJdk 11.0.2

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-11

I am trying to update from java 8 to OpenJdk 11. When I do mvn install from terminal, build works fine. But fails from (mac) intelliJ mvn install

Below is the startup command

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-11.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=/Users/myhome/Documents/WORKSPACES/something/develop "-Dmaven.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=53262 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMainV2 org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2018.2.6 -s /Users/myhome/Documents/config/maven/apache-maven-3.6.0/conf/settings.xml -Dmaven.repo.local=/Users/myhome/Documents/config/maven/repo install

Below is a sample error line

> [ERROR]
>   /Users/myhome/Documents/WORKSPACES/something/SomeClass.java:[7,33]
>   cannot access org.springframework.kafka.support
>
> [ERROR] zip END header not found

Any tip to fix it ?
(Already updated SDKs in platform settings to OpenJdk11, Maven>Runner is using OpenJdk11, Java Compiler updated to 11.

[image: MavenRunner[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qf8c.png)

[image: Jdk]

Comment: Try version from https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download - the compatible Maven version was updated there to 3.6+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to IntelliJ Version 2018.3.4 fixed this issue.
You could also try to delete `.gradle` folder as suggested by @Ninja

Comment: still meeting this problem at 2019.1.4

Comment: Encountered also in 2020.2

Comment: May be you can try 'File> Invalidate caches / Restart', or do a 'clean' re installation..

Answer (score 1):

I meet this error when build with gradlew, after remove the cache of gradle it works.

Solution in gradle wrapper build

```
rm ~/.gradle/*
```

If you use maven, maybe remove every thing in local maven wrapper will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

if you used intellij idea for create some code, maybe your forgot to enable gradle, when i am facing same error . i just enable gradle on my intellij idea and then my error is resolving.

you just choose **preferences -> plugins -> enable gradle if there is not enable**

hope this solution can help you.